# Ошибка: attribute is not allowed here

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nan.mathcalculators"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.equations"
        android:label="@string/equations" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.comb"
        android:label="@string/combinatorika" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.ag"
        android:label="@string/anal_geometr" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.complex"
        android:label="@string/complex_numbers" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.fractions"
        android:label="@string/Fractions" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.matrix"
        android:label="@string/matrix" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.svp"
        android:label="@string/plosh_obyom_perimetr" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.vectors"
        android:label="@string/vectors" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Следующие атрибуты выделяются красным цветом.

- `android:allowBackup`
- `android:icon`
- `android:theme`

Пытаюсь вызвать `intent` из уже вызванного `intent`, который в свою очередь вызван из `intent`. Хочу дописать в манифесте этот `intent`, например

```
    <activity
        android:name="nan.mathcalculators.menu1.vectors"
        android:label="@string/vectors" >
    </activity>
```

Но при сборке android studio эту часть кода успешно удаляет, хотя ошибок в коде и layoutах нет

Answer (score 1):

Я в коде не вижу использование uses-sdk, а без этого видимо андроид считает, что у Вас первая версия, а android:allowBackup доступно только с восьмой. Добавьте что то вида

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Comment: Да, я пробовал, но не помогает